# Unable to delete docker images

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, containers, docker-image

I'm newby in Devops culture and also eager to learn and use but I get stuck every time  when i try something new and now i can't delete images.
It says; it's being used by running container, stop it and then.....

See the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4X2H.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWdHT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94VGt.png)

Comment: Please post formatted code rather than screenshots. Screenshots break search, copy and paste, and are less accessible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Get running containers

```
docker ps
```

Get all running and stopped container

```
docker ps -a
```

Stop single container

```
docker stop <container_id>
```

Stop all containers

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

Remove single container

```
docker rm <container_id>
```

Remove all containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

Remove single image

```
docker rmi <image_id>
```

Remove all images

```
docker rmi $(docker images -q)
```

Remove everything from Docker host machine(use with caution because will delete everything like images, containers,networks etc)

```
docker system prune
```

Comment: "docker rm" requires at least 1 argument.
See 'docker rm --help'.

Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

Comment: @yunusemregörmüş  I have updated my answer will work now

Comment: Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete e704287ce753 (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container f01123318760

Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 79da37e5a3aa (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container 6d526abd025d

Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete fc838b21afbb (cannot be forced) - image is being used by running container cf8ccd96d231
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 0ee1b8a3ebe0 (cannot be f-***

Comment: @yunusemregörmüş try above commands it's working on my local. try again should definitely  work

Comment: i am struggling about one week. Nothing changed about simple commands

Answer (score 2):

You can just force remove the image even when there is a container that is still using it, if you don't mind doing that.

```
docker image rm <image-name> --force
```

Best way to delete all stopped containers is

```
docker container prune
```

As for the running containers, you should be able to list them with

```
docker container ls
```

add (--all) to see all (running/stopped) containers

```
docker container ls --all
```

Comment: Everything seems fine with that screenshot, do you see any problem with it?

Comment: And as I can see, it also deleted one container, wasn't it the one that was causing you the issue?

Comment: Those are system images used by kubernetes itself, you can't and should't remove them if you don't want to break your kubernetes/docker runtime.

Comment: thank you !
i guess that was the answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use `docker ps -a` to list all your running containers. You will find the ones still running. Stop them by using `docker stop NAMEOFTHECONTAINER` and remove them with `docker rm NAMEOFTHECONTAINER`.

Comment: There is no container displayed :(  
Did you see the first Screenshot.. Already doesn't exist at all and so i can't find the problematic

Comment: You can try to force deleting them. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188657/image-is-being-used-by-stopped-container/51189605